# How to choose a microphone for a laptop

Tags: laptop, microphone

I am teaching via Zoom from my Dell laptop, and some students complain that they do not hear me well enough, so I would like to try to use an external microphone (instead of the laptop built-in microphone). I saw several options:

- A headset that includes both headphones and a microphone. It has the advantage that it can be plugged into the single headphone-hole in laptop. However, I am not sure the microphone is strong enough.
- A stand-alone USB microphone, that stands on the table rather than near my mouth, with "58 dB" sensitivity (not sure what it means);
- A more expensive stand-alone USB microphone, with "50 dB" sensitivity.

My specific questions are:

1. Does the microphone that comes with a headset has the same quality of a stand-alone microphone?
2. Does a microphone that stands on the table produce the same sound quality for the hearers as a microphone that sits just next to my mouth?
3. What is the difference between "58 dB" and "50 dB"?
4. What other parameters are important for choosing a microphone that will help me be heard well through Zoom?

Comment: Blue Snowball is good for this.  It sits on a table and does not need to be close to your mouth. It is just a microphone (at least the one I have). A headset is separate.  dB are a logarithmic scale so 3 dB is a noticeable change.

Comment: @Ramhound A factor of 10 in what - in the volume? Does this mean that with the 50 dB microphone I will be heard 10 times louder?

Comment: I have found that i get EXCELLENT coverage from the boom mic attached to my headset.  I have purchased both cheapie amazon headsets and a more expensive corsair one.  Both provide EXCELLENT sound for zoom meetings.

Comment: @John when the microphone is not next to your mouth - isn't it more sensitive to surrounding noise?

Comment: Not with my Blue Snowball. It needs to be close but not close like a hand held mike

Comment: This wasn't a shopping request, it was a "how do I choose?". I was halfway through an answer when it was incorrectly closed.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Half the questions cannot be answered without more information.  The only question I can answer is the question with regards to the different between 50 dB and 58 dB.  The last question is clearly a question that is going to get a ton of product recommendations

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi - No;  50 dB microphone would be more sensitive then 58 dB.  Which one you desire entirely depends on your environment.  58 dB would pick up less background noise, but that can also be handled by software, entirely depends on what the actual cause of your students inability to hear you.

Comment: The dB value is completely irrelevant. It might matter for the max SPL of a two grand pro mic, it certainly doesn't for anything you're gonna stick on your head for a "phone call".

Comment: "What is the difference between "58 dB" and "50 dB"?" - The difference between 50 dB and 58 dB is nearly a factor of 10.  50 db has a power ratio of 100,000 while 60 dB has a power ration of 1,000,000.  The 2 dB difference between 58 dB and 60 dB would be pretty negligible.  The specification is simply indicating that the microphone will pickup a 50 dB while the other microphone will be a factor of 10 less sensitive.

Comment: It is utterly irrelevant to the topic. I've tried a $3000 Neumann U87 on Skype. Result… poor. Speakers influencing more than any other factor. (Did I mention I'm a retired sound engineer ;)You gotta use a headset to reduce spill & interference. Get that tiny cheap headset mic right in your face, very slightly off to one side so it doesn't pop, & off you go..

Comment: BTW, several misleading comments above - "factor of 10"…  10x the *power* but only twice the apparent *volume*. Changing the sensitivity will not change the "amount of background noise" in the slightest; you will just turn up or down the overall volume to compensate - moving the background noise exactly as much as the main voice signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A response from a former telephone company Long Lines tech (Inward 813+131, 813+024) turned professional radio newsman (WSPD) and broadcaster (WLQR) turned IT tech follows.

Take every spec offered for a product with a grain (or pound) of salt. Nobody enforces the accuracy of specs.

The digital transmission of sound can be utterly fantastic, or utterly atrocious, and there are so many other factors beyond the quality of your equipment that spending a lot of $$$ on equipment without spending $,$$$ or $$,$$$ on digital line quality is *futile*. I used to do dedicated audio lines for a living.   Skype and Zoom can make anyone sound awful.

**1**: *Q: Does the microphone that comes with a headset have the same quality of a stand-alone microphone?*  A: Only with expensive, broadcaster-grade headsets, but the difference in general is very small. The mike in headsets is always radically better than the mike built into a laptop because you've eliminated the fan and keyboard noise, plus the drive noise if you have an HDD instead of an SSD.

**2**: *Q: Does a microphone that stands on the table produce the same sound quality for the hearers as a microphone that sits just next to my mouth?* It can; see Microphone placement, below. Table mikes can provide better or worse sound quality, and that's utterly dependent on where your mouth is, in relation to the mike. Headset mikes have the virtue of consistency; they will always be right there by your head.

**3**: *Q: What is the difference between "58 dB" and "50 dB"?* A: 58db is in the range of [normal conversation](https://www.industrialfansdirect.com/pages/dba-sones-decibel-levels), whereas 50db is typically the [volume of rustling paper](https://www.nationalsafetyinc.com/Assets/Noise_Thermometer.pdf). A [decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Perception) is a logarithmic ratio of power in sound, and with every 3db increase, double the power is put into the sound. However, your ears are analog, not digital, and your brain compensates, so it take 3db for most folks to notice a perceptible increase in sound. For a sound of uniform frequency to seem twice as loud, it's got to [increase by 10db](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-levelchange.htm).

**4**: A: Frequency response and mike placement.

If you want to be heard with full, rich, sound, a microphone with fairly flat (uniform) response outside of the narrowband Plain Old Telephone Service microphones normally restricted to 300 - 3,400 Hz is desirable, but that won't cost an arm and a leg. I have used multiple headsets with microphones in the < $50 range and get better-than-POTS sound output on all of them.

Microphone placement is also very important; make sure the mike is not shoved up out of the way, but if folks hear you *Popping Your Ps* ,  move the mike a little out of the way or put an open-cell  foam rubber 'sock' over the mike.

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice the frequency response. Just to understand what this parameter means: is a range of "20 Hz - 20 kHz" better than "40 Hz - 18 kHz" or vice-versa? I also saw another parameter "resistance" - what does it mean?

Comment: Erel - it frankly makes no difference on a human voice. The voice is really only operating between 100Hz & maybe 6 - 8 kHz.Phones don't even use that much & you can still have a perfectly intelligible conversation. The other thing is that spec on cheap mics just *lie*. they twist the truth knowing that the consumer doesn't actually know what the figures really mean. You really can ignore most of what they say.

Comment: @Tetsujin is absolutely right. 20-20k is better than 40-18k, but you probably won't hear the difference unless you are a 'golden ear' who spends kilobucks on hi-fi gear and it makes _no_ difference for voice.

Comment: You don't hear resistance or (proper term here) impedance. It's a property of electronics; how much opposition to a given amount of current a device puts up. Matching the impedance of devices gives the best result.

Comment: @K7AYY [I need to be away for the night, so I'll check back in the morning] but wondering if a recommendation for a USB headset would be advantageous. Would at least eliminate the poor mic pre in the laptop. I'm gonna vote to re=open, too.

Comment: Erel, other folks have decided this discussion does not belong here. If you wish to know more, copy your question and ask it in https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com